# how to access individual emitter property of particle system in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm very new to cocos2d and iphone , I have started working with particle system in which I'm implementing particle systems using CCparticlesystemQuad , now I want to use each one particle system with it's own property .. like CCparticlessytemQuad object can have gravity property , so what i want to do is set gravity to each of my ccparticlestystemQuad object which should be independent. I'm using plist file to access my image source like sprite and texture. Can I achieve this ??

in my helloworld.h, I have declared ,

```
CCParticleSystem *emitter;
```

and in my helloworld.m, I'm using it this way:

```
emitter =[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"stars.plist"];

emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"1.png"];

[self addChild: emitter z:1];
```

now, I want property gravity , something like this

```
emitter.gravity
```

I want to use this gravity property with more then one Emitter objects , is there any way possible through which I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to set the gravity of another emmiter as the gravity of the first emitter!?

Just do it like that:

```
[emitter2 setGravity:emitter.gravity];
```

You can set or get any emitter properties, just have to have access to the variable.

Comment: i want to access gravity as individual for all emitters :)

Comment: Can you be more clear? I think I'm not getting what you want to do.

Comment: i meant .. i have say 40 emitters .. i want to set gravity of each of those emitters individually .so , according to you , i have to set 40 variables for gravity !!! is that so ...

Comment: Each CCParticleSystem already have a gravety property, if all of your emitters will have the same value you can set them [emitter1 setGravity: x]; [emitter2 setGravity: x]; (where x is any number you want), if they have different values you will have to set each one of them, but you dont need new variables. You can do it like this --> [emitter1 setGravity:10]; [emitter2 setGravity:6]; Or use a function f(x) to calculate the gravity of each emitter based on one (or some) parameters.